# Add value to DF if column value matches value in list of another DF

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a `DF1`:

```
+---------------+                                                               
|        colName|
+---------------+
|              a|
|              m|
|              f|
|              o|
+---------------+
```

And another `DF2`:

```
+---------------+                                                               
|            col|
+---------------+
|    [a,b,b,c,d]|
|      [e,f,g,h]|
|        [i,j,k]|
|    [l,m,n,o,p]|
+---------------+
```

If the list stored in `DF2.col` has elements that are in `DF1.colName` a new DataFrame(or `DF2`) should be such:

```
+---------------+---------------+                                                               
|            col|           bool|
+---------------+---------------+
|      [a,b,c,d]|              1|              #Since "a" was in `DF1.colName`
|      [e,f,g,h]|              1|              #Since "f" was in `DF1.colName`
|        [i,j,k]|              0|              #Since no element was not in `DF1.colName`
|    [l,m,n,o,p]|              1|              #Since "f" was in `DF1.colName`
+---------------+---------------+
```

I have previously thought of using [UserDefinedFunction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/udf.html) and the Pandas function [isIn()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) but to no avail as such. Anything that'd help me guide through this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is it pandas or spark ?

Comment: Thank you @Steven for pointing it out. It's PySpark by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `pyspark` , you can check with `array_intersect` , then determine the size of array with a case statement using `when+otherwise`;

```
arr = df1.select("colName").rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()
size = F.size(F.array_intersect("col",F.array([F.lit(i) for i in arr])))
df2.withColumn("t",F.when(size>0,1).otherwise(0)).show()

+---------------+---+
|            col|  t|
+---------------+---+
|[a, b, b, c, d]|  1|
|   [e, f, g, h]|  1|
|      [i, j, k]|  0|
|[l, m, n, o, p]|  1|
+---------------+---+
```

Comment: Well written(neat), and achieves what I wanted to. Brownie points(Answer accepted) for writing the one based on PySpark. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert values to `set`s and use `isdisjoint`:

```
s = set(DF1.colName)
DF2['bool'] = DF2['col'].apply(lambda x: not set(x).isdisjoint(s)).astype(int)

print (DF2)
               col  bool
0  [a, b, b, c, d]     1
1     [e, f, g, h]     1
2        [i, j, k]     0
3  [l, m, n, o, p]     1
```

Or use intersection, convert to bool for `False` to empty set and then to integers for `True, False` to `1,0` mapping:

```
s = set(DF1.colName)
DF2['bool'] = DF2['col'].apply(lambda x: bool(set(s).intersection(x))).astype(int)

print (DF2)
               col  bool
0  [a, b, b, c, d]     1
1     [e, f, g, h]     1
2        [i, j, k]     0
3  [l, m, n, o, p]     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df2['bool'] = df2.col.apply(lambda x: any(df1.colName.isin(x))).astype(int)
print(df2)
```

**Output:**

```
               col  bool
0  [a, b, b, c, d]     1
1     [e, f, g, h]     1
2        [i, j, k]     0
3  [l, m, n, o, p]     1
```